# 'symfony' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, symfony, console, composer-php, command

> I install new symfony project by using this command

```
composer  create-project symfony/website-skeleton sym-toturial
```

> Now when I run this command to start the server and run the project it is not working

```
symfony server:start
```

[image]

Comment: `symfony` is a standalone executable that needs to be explicitly installed.  The docs have the details for your operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did install a Symfony project. It only contains php, yaml, txt files, no executables.

The command symfony is a standalone program.

[You can download it here](https://symfony.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

Now installer support is deprecated. You have to install via scoop

Install Scoop:

```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser # Optional: Needed to run a remote script the first time
> irm get.scoop.sh | iex
```

Install Symfony CLI

```
scoop install symfony-cli
```

Then create new project using symfony command

```
symfony new --webapp my_project
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed **Symfony-CLI** with **scoop**:

Make sure that `C:\Users\REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_USER_ACCOUNT_NAME\scoop\shims` is in your **PATH variable** under USER VARIABLES FOR ...

[image: environment variables]
[image: user environment variables]

**Hint:** To edit your environment variables, type "envir" in the "Search the web and Windows" box and select "Edit environment variables for your account".